# LINQ, Lists and Add items question

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have the following which is an array

```
package.Resources
```

If I use

```
package.Resources.ToList().Add(resouce);
```

package.Resources doesn't actually contain the new item.

I have to use

```
var packageList = package.Resources.ToList();
packageList.Add(resource);
package.Resources = packageList.ToArray();
```

Why is that?

Comment: What is your intended result when you 'add' a new item to an **array** ? An array with the new item at some (which?) index, replacing any item that might have been there before? A new, larger array? (from your last code it looks like this last)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ToList()` creates a completely new, different list based on the original array.

LINQ is read-only; Language INtegrated **Query** - it is only querying the data, not modifying it. All LINQ methods produce a *projection* - e.g., they project the original sequence into a new one, so you're always working against that.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `package.Resources.ToList().Add(resouce);`, it's functionally the same as doing this:

```
var resourcesAsList = new List<WhateverTypeResourcesContains>();
foreach(var item in package.Resources)
{
    resourcesAsList.Add(item);
}
var resourcesAsList.Add(resouce);
```

What this means is that `package.Resources` hasn't been modified, you've created a `List<T>` that contains each item that package.Resources contained.

Answer (score 2):

Exanding upon what [Rex said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469329/linq-lists-and-add-items-question/3469339#3469339), when you call `.ToList()` on an array object, what you are saying is, "Make me a brand new `List` object that's a distinct reference from the original array, but use the objects from my original array as the objects in my list."

Because arrays are fixed in size, there's really no way to `Add()` an item to it without copying the existing array to a new array that has an increased capacity (even `ReDim Preserve` in the VB world copies the array behind the scense).

Because of this, you should ask yourself why you are using an array if you don't know the total number of items in the array when you instantiate it.  When you know the number of items or when you are instantiating the array from an existing `List` or `IEnumerable`, arrays can be a decent light-weight way of holding a collection of objects.  However, when you don't know the capacity until runtime and the source is not an `IEnumerable` , a `List` might be a better option because it is built to grow in capacity as items are added.

I use the following collection types as properties in my classes:

- `IEnumerable`

  - I use `IEnumerable` when I'm going to be iterating over a collection that already exists and I won't be adding to it.  For example, if I query a directory for its files and I want to have those files as a property in a class, I might use `public IEnumerable<FileInfo> DirectoryFiles {get; set;}`.
  - `IEnumerable` allows me to query over an existing set of data, but I don't necessarily care what collection it is, as long as it implements `IEnumerable`.
- `List<T>`

  - I use a `List<T>` when I need a collection that could grow or shrink dynamically, i.e. the collection doesn't arealdy exist somewhere else and I may need to add or remove items from it.
  - A good example of this might be if you are allowing a user to add and remove items to a list box in the user interface of your application.  Since the items in the list box might grow or shrink, a `List<T>` makes sense.
- `ObservableCollection<T>`

  - I use this type of collection in the Silverlight/WPF world because it has built-in events for when the number of items in the collection changes. This is especially handy for data-binding scenarios when you want a UI element to automatically update when the list changes.

I almost never use Arrays explicitly unless I'm consuming an object that already has arrays.  Granted, they're a nice lightweight way in which store a collection, but I can usually get by with the 3 types I listed above.

Comment: It actually is a List in the class, but the object is returned from a webmethod, which returns it as an array.  And I'm adding an item to the object, then passing it to another webmethod to save it.  Yes, ideally this wouldn't go through a webservice, but, I have no choice.

Comment: @Chad I know how that goes. I generally end up using lists for lots of the same reasone, i.e. when I'm forced to.

Answer (score 1):

The property `Resources` is returning an `IEnumerable`.  `Enumerable.ToList()` builds a *new* list from this `IEnumerable`.  You are then adding an item to a new list, not the original collection that `Resources` is accessing, hence your update is having no affect.